# How to force UITextView to use default NSFont attribute when the user types anywhere

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nstextstorage

I have a `UITextView` that is displaying `NSAttributedText` with two different Fonts. Imagine:
"Sample **Text** here."

If the user deletes up to the character "**t**", or select the middle of the text, and type "hahaha", the new text will be in **Bold**. So it will look like:

"Sample **Tehahahaxt** here." OR "Sample **Texthahaha** here."

**SO:** How can I prevent this? in other words, how can I force the `UITextView` to only use a specific font when a user starts typing, *no matter where it is*!

**NOTE:** I have already tried setting the `typingAttributes` property of `UITextView` in `-textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:` but it changes content size and that won't work for me.

Comment: You need to post your code here otherwise is hard to tell what is happening

Comment: There's no need for code. You can replicate this by a UITextView with attributed text and giving a word a BOLD font.

Answer (score -1):

Implement textViewDidChange: method in your delegate and perform the following.

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
   NSAttributedString *attributedText = textView.attributedText;
   if (attributedText)
   {
      textView.text = attributedText.string;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. This eliminates all formatting.

Comment: I don't want to manipulate my string or its attributes. I just want the new text to always keep a certain format.